# Generating Radio Button Result Depending On TextArea Value

Tags: javascript, forms, function, if-statement, radio-button

A few days ago I did not manage to generate a result from my radio button, I managed to solve that problem now. My other problem is how do I generate ONLY few set of the radio button depending on TextArea value changes;

For Example in this code

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function generatetest() {

codeOne = document.docContainer.text1.value;
codeTwo = document.docContainer.number2.value;

function firstType(){

var codeFour = 0;

for( i = 0; i < document.docContainer.radio4.length; i++ )
    {
    if( document.docContainer.radio4[i].checked == true )
    codeFour = document.docContainer.radio4[i].value;
    }

var codeTen = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < document.docContainer.radio10.length; i++ )
    {
    if( document.docContainer.radio10[i].checked == true )
    codeTen = document.docContainer.radio10[i].value;
    }

document.docContainer.textarea12.value = codeOne + codeTwo + codeFour + codeTen;
}

function secondType(){

var codeSix = 0;

for( i = 0; i < document.docContainer.radio6.length; i++ )
    {
    if( document.docContainer.radio6[i].checked == true )
    codeFour = document.docContainer.radio6[i].value;
    }

var codeEleven = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < document.docContainer.radio11.length; i++ )
    {
    if( document.docContainer.radio11[i].checked == true )
    codeTen = document.docContainer.radio11[i].value;
    }

document.docContainer.textarea12.value = codeOne + codeTwo + codeSix + codeEleven
}

if (document.docContainer.number2.value="1")
{
firstType();
}
else if (document.docContainer.number2.value="2")
{
secondType();
}


}
</script>
```

The code is working, problem is, even though I insert the value on textarea "number2" as "2", the code still generate firstType() result

Am Im using wrong if-statement or what and how do I go around about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be more fun to read, but Putting quotes around your numbers is causing javascript to treat them like text. Is this what you want to be doing?

Comment: well I tried to change that to

``if (document.docContainer.number2.value=1)
{
firstType();
}
else if (document.docContainer.number2.value=2)
{
secondType();}``

but Im still getting the same result

Comment: put a == double equal sign, see if that does it. keep it even if it doesn't. just means you have another problem. also log the value of the object you are comparing to the number to make sure it is the value it is supposed to be.

Comment: okay I've tried

`if (document.docContainer.number2.value==1)`

doesnt work. Result return as "0"

so I've tried

`if (document.docContainer.text1.value=="one")`

doesnt work either. Result return as "0"

it seems using double equal sign doesnt make much of difference.
if I removed the quotes, the code doesnt work at all

Comment: if you do console.log(number2); right before your if statement what does that log in your command window?

Comment: I did that and I get - Uncaught ReferenceError: number2 is not defined

Comment: k, could you edit your code to throw a few notes in just so i could get the gist of what is supposed to be going on here as far as logic flow.

Comment: I dont understand how to throw a few notes in, but just in case if you need the whole thing http://pastebin.com/j1LcuhDc

what Im trying to do is just that depending on `codeTwo = document.docContainer.number2.value;` the generate result of the radio button will switch to either `firstType();` or `secondType();`

the problem is, result kept showing `firstType();` no matter if I used number/text for `codeTwo = document.docContainer.number2.value;` that which supposed to get `secondType` once certain number/text - typed/selected

Comment: aight I got the form loaded in front of me. to make this clear. someone types text in the first box, selects any number?, and then chooses a radio button selection four different times, they place comments? and then what is supposed to happen

Comment: well the form is just a test, the 1st box is a test for text, second for number, so I tested out if a user used number "2" on second box that only allows number, then the result for radio button should generated for second set of radio button, the comment box is where the generated result came out

Comment: so considering maybe numbers didnt work out, I tried using the 1st box, and using text instead eg; one/two but still doesnt seems to work out and back to square one

Comment: Alright I just read through it, if you are ever going to do anything to do with computer code ever again you gotttttaa learn how to format it and comment it. formating tells you where functions start and stop at a quick glanc and comments for javascript are just notes to yourself you do // at the beginning of a line and you can write whatever. I am pretty sure your problem is that you never attach an eventlistener to your code, an eventListener would wait for user input and then run your code. google it, I will be back online in like 3 or 4 hours.

Comment: I tried `if(document.docContainer.text1.value=="this")` as replacement for `function firstType()` and `else if(document.docContainer.text1.value=="that")` as replacement for `function secondType()` Im still getting 0 on the radio button result. I went to check on eventlistener but what I need is that whenever I click on generate button, the result of radio button that come out depends on textarea value, for example if I typed "this", the result that will come out will be the 1st and 2nd radio value, and when I typed "that" the result that will come out will be 3rd and 4th radio value

Comment: I managed to get it to work by using `if (document.docContainer.number2.value==1)
{
firstType();
}
else if (document.docContainer.number2.value==2)
{
secondType();
}`

full code example: http://pastebin.com/H0iifn5y